# Will a HashMap<String, WeakReference<>> potentially cause a memory leak if not explicitly cleaned up?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, weak-references

I've run across a piece of code that I am convinced will cause an inadvertent memory leak:

```
Object user = getUser("Bob");

Map<String, WeakReference<Object>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Bob", new WeakReference( user ) );
```

The purpose of this map is to cache the Objects and to have them automatically cleared from the map by the GC when they are no longer strongly referenced.

However, the way I see it is if the key isn't a weak reference as well, then once the Object is GC'ed, there will still be an entry in the hash map with the key pointing to null.  Hence the map will still contain the same number of rows, just all pointing to null values.

So in the above example, once all strong references to `user` are released, and the GC destroys the `Object`, the entry in the map will be equiv to :

```
map.put("Bob", null );
```

So unless there is a cleanup routine that flushes all keys with null values, my map will continue to grow.

So then the question becomes how to fix this?  Is there a map construct that I can use which will automatically flush my entry if the value is destroyed?

I contemplated doing something like:

```
Object user = getUser("Bob");

Map<String, WeakReference<Object>> map = new WeakHashMap<>();
map.put(user.getUsername(), new WeakReference( user ) );
```

But that seems like a very limited use case where my key has to be an object retrieved from my value.  With the `WeakHashMap` my key cannot be a String constant (ie: "Bob") or there won't be any other references to it, and the GC will clear the object from my map.

Is there some other cache construct that provides all this functionality instead?

Answer (score 4):

You are right in that the collection of the referent does not remove the mapping, however, the result is not equivalent to

```
map.put("Bob", null );
```

it will be equivalent to

```
map.put("Bob", new WeakReference<>(null) );
```

so you’re not only having a dangling entry instance, but also a dangling cleared `WeakReference` instance.

When you use

```
Map<String, WeakReference<User>> map = new WeakHashMap<>();
User user = getUser("Bob");
map.put(user.getUsername(), new WeakReference( user ) );
```

you get the desired semantics, assuming that `user.getUsername()` returns a reference to the string instance stored in the `User` object, to ensure that it stays strongly reachable as long as the `User` is strongly reachable.

I don’t see any limitation here. Since the string instance stored within the `User` does exist, there is no overhead in referencing exactly the same string instance as map key as long as the `User` instance exist. You can still use string constants as lookup key ala `User u = map.get("Bob");`, as their equality still is determined in terms of `String.hashCode()` and `String.equals()`. If you `put` the mapping using the string constant `"Bob"` the mapping will usually persist at least as long as the *code* containing the constant is alive (and each other code that used the same literal during this lifetime), likely the entire application. But where’s the sense in using a different string instance as key than stored in the referent?

Note that `WeakHashMap` has to deal with the same issue, entries are not removed automatically. It has to use a [`ReferenceQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue.html) to discover when a referent has been collected to remove its associated entry from the table. [This cleanup](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/WeakHashMap.java#317) happens whenever you invoke a method on it, so when you don’t invoke methods on it, the table won’t get cleanup, but since this cleanup happens for every insertion, you are protected against the ever-growing scenario.

Answer (score 2):

1. > if the key isn't a weak reference as well, then once the Object is GC'ed, there will still be an entry in the hash map with the key pointing to null.

With the key pointing to a non-null `WeakReference` which points to a null referent.

> Hence the map will still contain the same number of rows, just all pointing to null values.

No, see above.

The solution is to use a `WeakHashMap<String, WeakReference<Object>>`, which has a background activity that spots the weak keys being collected, via a `ReferenceQueue`, and removes the corresponding mappings. Better still, a `WeakHashMap<String, WeakReference<User>>`. However:

2. If the keys are string literals they aren't collectable anyway.

It's a bit rich to describe this as a memory leak. The Map itself is a memory leak. If you don't want references to your objects, don't store them in a Map.

Comment: Why are string literals not collectable?  Aren't they just objects like any other that follow the same rules? Just because strings are immutable I don't see why they would be treated any differently.

Comment: @Eric B.: The specification mandates that identical string literals are resolved to the same instance, which is implemented using the intern table. While strings referenced by this table are collectible, a detected in-between collection of a string instance referenced by a literal would not match the specified behavior of always resolving to the same instance. So collection of such strings is only possible when all code containing the literal has been collected too, to make it undetectable that the collection happened. For code loaded by the application class loader, this can never happen.

Comment: @holger thanks.  I realized that just as I was reading your response below.  Would doing `map.put( new String("Bob"), new WeakReference(user))` circumvent the string literal issue, or is that considered the same thing? Given that I am intentionally creating a string object, I would expect it to treat it as such and not a literal, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Eric B.: it would solve the string literal issue, but create a new issue. Since nothing references the new string instance created via `new String("Bob")`, it is eligible for garbage collection immediately, so the `WeakHashMap` could remove the mapping right the next time you query it. That’s exactly the implication of “*intentionally creating a string object*”; that instance is distinct from the object representing the literal and it is distinct from the object referenced by the `User` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct.

1. `Map<String,WeakReference<Object>>` is used in situations when "lingering" keys do not present a problem, because they are a lot smaller than the objects stored in the map. In situations like that having lots of keys mapped to emptied weak references does not strain the memory resources of the system enough for you to notice.
2. You can use `WeakHashMap<K,V>` for situations when you would rather have keys garbage collected, but you are absolutely right about using `String` constants with it: this would indeed defeat the purpose. Typically, you use a custom key type that overrides `equals` with reference equality.